# Vue.js + Laravel - Delete object

Tags: javascript, php, vuejs2, laravel-5.3

I trying to build a CRUD using Vue.js and Laravel, but... I can Save, Read and Update the only problem is the Delete, can someone help me?

My index.blade.php: (to get id)

```
<div class="modal inmodal" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content animated bounceInRight">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Fechar</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Delete</h4>     
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <p>Do you want delete this row <strong>ID: </strong> @{{competency.id}} <strong>Nome: </strong> @{{competency.name}} </p> 
          </div>
       </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" v-on:click="remove(competency.id)">Delete</button>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

My Vue.js

```
 var competency = new Vue({
        el: '#competency',
        filters: {
            moment: function (date) {
                return moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
            }
        },
        data: {
            competency: "",
            searchQuery: '',
            search: {
                name: ""
            },
            list: [],
        },
        methods: {
            fillCompetency: function(comp){
              if (comp == null)
                this.competency = {
                    id : "",
                    name : "",
                    description : "",
                }
                else
                  this.competency = comp;
            },
            del: function(index){
              this.fillCompetency(this.list[index]);
              $("#delete").modal('show');
            },
            remove: function(id){
              var self = this;
              self.competency._token = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
              $.ajax({
                url: "competency",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                traditional: true,
                data: id
              }).done(function(data){
                  self.filter();
                  $("#delete").modal('hide');
                  fillCompetency(null);
              });
            }
        },
        mounted: function () {
            this.filter();
        },
        watch: {

        }
     });
```

My Controller

```
class CompetencyController extends Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        $this -> middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index(){
        return view('competency/index');
    }

    public function filter(){
        $list = Competency::all();
        return response()->json($list);
    }

    public function create(){

    }

    public function store(Request $request){

        $entity = new Competency;

        if ($request->id != null){          
            $entity = Competency::find($request->id);
        }

        if ($request->name == null && $request->description == null){
            $entity = Competency::find($id);
            return response()->json($entity->delete());
        }

        $entity->name = $request->name;
        $entity->description = $request->description;

        return response()->json($entity->save());
    }

    public function delete($id){
        $entity = new Competency;
        $entity = Competency::find($id);
        return response()->json($entity->delete());
    }

    public function show($id){

    }

    public function edit($id){

    }

    public function update(Request $request){

    }

    public function destroy($id){
        $entity = new Competency;
        $entity = Competency::find($id);
        return response()->json($entity->delete());
    }
  }
```

My route:

```
Route::resource('competency', 'CompetencyController');
```

The problem is, i have tried to send DELETE method on remove from Vue, but i get an error called 500 (Internal Error Serve) but on laravel.log dont show anything, i have tried send DELETE method because the desroy method is called correct? so i get error instead i send by POST method to store and check if just id is not null, if not i called method delete by laravel, so any method that i hev tried dont work, can someone help me?

I think that the error is on Route, but i tried everything too

Comment: What the error on chrome developer console . check the network tab

Comment: @iambatman on the console show "jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/competency 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-3.1.1.min.js:4" but on laravel.log dont show anything

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your delete method to this

```
// your route for delete should be 
 Route::delete('competency/{id}', 'Controller@delete');


// controller 
public function delete($id){
    $responseMsg = "Competency not found"; 
    $status = 404;
    $entity = Competency::find($id);
    if ($entity != null ){
      $responseMsg = "Competency deleted";
      $status = 204;
      $entity->delete(); // delete method is void, doen't return any value
    }
    return response()->json(['message' => $responseMsg], $status);
}
```

Vue.js remove method

```
remove: function(id){
              var self = this;
              self.competency._token = window.Laravel.csrfToken;
              $.ajax({
                url: "competency/"+id,
                type: "DELETE", // 
                traditional: true
              // if you use POST method, data has to be a json object
              // {id: id} then in laravel you could do $request->input('id');

              }).done(function(data){
                  self.filter();
                  $("#delete").modal('hide');
                  fillCompetency(null);
              });
            }
```

Comment: But to send the id for this method, how can i put on vue.js route and method? can i put type 'post', url 'competency' or url:'competency.delete'?